# Приложение с GridView отвечает чёрным экраном

Tags: android, xml, gridview

Разбираю GridView, смотрю видео на ютубе. Например этого [парня](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NoHxfIu0MQ).

Код приведён ниже.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.theend;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView myGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        myGrid.setAdapter(new PokedexAdapter(this));
    }
}

class Pokemon{
    int imageId;
    String pokemonName;
    Pokemon(int imageId,String pokemonName){
        this.imageId=imageId;
        this.pokemonName=pokemonName;
    }
}

class PokedexAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<Pokemon> list;
    private Context context;

    PokedexAdapter(Context context){

        this.context=context;
        list = new ArrayList<Pokemon>();

        Resources res=context.getResources();
        String[] tempPokemonNames = res.getStringArray(R.array.pokemon_names);
        int[] pokemonImages = {
                R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,
                R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,R.drawable.six,
                R.drawable.seven,R.drawable.eight,R.drawable.nine
        };

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            Pokemon tempPokemon = new Pokemon(pokemonImages[i],tempPokemonNames[i]);
            list.add(tempPokemon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView myPokemon;
        ViewHolder(View v){
            myPokemon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row==null){

            //first time
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item,viewGroup,false);
            holder=new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);

        }else{

            //recycling
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Pokemon temp=list.get(i);
        holder.myPokemon.setImageResource(temp.imageId);

        return row;
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.theend.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:text="Информация" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="375dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Single_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/one" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TheEnd</string>
    <string-array name="pokemon_names">
        <item>001. Бульбазавр</item>
        <item>002. Ивизавр</item>
        <item>003. Венузавр</item>
        <item>004. Чармандер</item>
        <item>005. Чармелеон</item>
        <item>006. Чаризард</item>
        <item>007. Сквиртл</item>
        <item>008. Вартортл</item>
        <item>009. Бластойз</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

По идее, на этом этапе приложение должно показывать GridView с 9 изображениями без какого либо взаимодействия.

Но приложения выводит чёрный экран. Прошу наставления. Указания на любые мои глупые ошибки. Рад любому совету.

**P.S.** вот формат изображений на всякий случай.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось таковым.

Из файла **Single_item.xml** в элементе *ImageView* убрать следующую строчку:

*android:src="@drawable/one"*

Так как мы программно задаём файл для *ImageView*, то задавать его в *xml* будет не правильно. Вроде я разобрался. По крайней мере заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]